# Will changing server_id on master break replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have few MySql absolutely isolated trees, each one of them has one master and few slaves.

For purposes of automation I need to set the same **server_id** to all masters (this will simplify the usage of pt-heartbeat which needs **server_id**). This should be perfectly fine since all trees are isolated.

I am wondering, if I change **server_id** on master, restart master, do I damage the replication? Of course there are will be a short brake of replication, but will this break replication completely?

The question is does changing **server_id** break replication completely, does it change positions in bin-log?

UPDATE: actually I don't have to restart mysql, I can just change it in console with SET GLOBAL server_id=xxx, in this case I don't need restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not break replication provided you do not choose a bad server_id. Here is why:

Given this server_id setup

- Master with server_id 1
- Slave with server_id 2

Here is what happens with Replication

- Master completes and SQL command
- Master records its server_id along with SQL
- Slave reads Binary Logs of Master and stores them in Relay Logs
- Slave reads reads Relay Logs and sees server_id 1
- Since the Master server_id and Slave server_id do not match, Slaves run the SQL

What happens if you set the Master's server_id to 2 ?

- Master completes and SQL command
- Master records its server_id along with SQL
- Slave reads Binary Logs of Master and stores them in Relay Logs
- Slave reads reads Relay Logs and sees server_id 1
- Since the Master server_id and Slave server_id match, Slaves does not run the SQL

The only bad server_id to assign is the same server_id as the Slave. Other than that, Replication should not break.

Answer (score 0):

@com, the answer is yes, changing only the MySQL Master’s server_id will most likely break the replication. In order to make that change work, follow these steps:

1. First, stop all Slaves.
2. Run show slave status and save the results on each Slave.
3. Change the server_id on your Master in my.cnf and by running SET GLOBAL.
4. Now, on each Slave, use CHANGE MASTER query to set the Master's new server_id but make sure that all other details remain the same.
5. Finally, run start slave on all Slaves.

One note, changing the server_id on a Slave only however, should not impact replication.

Good luck :)